# Xpath to locate a table data cell element based on a condition from another cell

Tags: selenium, xpath

Is there a way to locate a particular table data cell element based in a condition from another cell in the same row by XPath? I was able to locate the conditional cell by Xpath **(//td[@role="gridcell"]//span[@title="Professional"])[1]**. However, I am not sure how do I locate the target cell in the same row based on the result of the condition. The goal is to locate&click the anchor element in the target table header by the condition of title=professional from the other cell in the same row.

```
<table>
  ...
  <tbody>
    <tr>..</tr>
    <tr>..</tr>
    ...
    <tr>
      <td>..</td>
      <th>
        <span class="xxx">
          <a class="yyy" title="my_title">..</a>
        </span>
      </th>
      <td role="gridcell">
        <span class="abc">
          <span title="Professional">Professional</span> 
        </span>            
      </td>
      <td>..</td>
    </tr>
    ... 
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: So which element do you want to choose finally? Is it `<a class="yyy" title="my_title">..</a>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you refer to the `<a class="yyy" title="my_title">..</a>` element as anchor element, you can use this XPath-1.0 expression

```
//td[@role='gridcell' and span/span[@title='Professional']]/preceding-sibling::th[1]/span/a
```

Another valid XPath based on the `<tr>` element would be

```
//tr[td[@role='gridcell' and span/span[@title='Professional']]]/th/span/a
```